# How to know number of elements on a level in a complete binary search tree mathematically?

Tags: computer-science, trees, binary

So I was thinking if it's possible to know how many nodes exist on a particular binary tree level mathematically.

I came with the formula (where $n$ is the level):
$$2^{n-1}$$

But I didn't consider the fact that few of the parent node could not have leaf at all. Programmatically one would simply go over the parent node and count the leaf nodes, but I'm wondering if there is a way to define it mathematically. Consider this image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5njY5.png)

Can I mathematically know how many elements exist on level $5$ while respecting the fact that some parent nodes could not have their leaf nodes?

Comment: Your formula is correct for every level above the bottom one. You can express the number of nodes in the bottom level as the difference between the total number of nodes (presumably given) and the number of nodes in the other levels.

Comment: @Karl Right, that makes sense. I mean if the total number of nodes are not given then it would be quite impossible to mathematically derive without counting right?